# scrollHeight is inaccurate due to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a div that has dynamic content prepended at certain intervals. After this content is loaded I need the scrollbar to go to the bottom of the div, but it only goes a portion of the way down because the rendering hasn't completed. I've confirmed this by using a setTimeout before scrolling the div. Is it possible to wait for the rendering to complete before scrolling down?

Here is the code that scrolls:

```
// AJAX loads content into the div #myDiv

document.querySelector("#myDiv").scrollTop = document.querySelector("#myDiv").scrollHeight;
```

Comment: HTML validators will tend to complain at you if your `<img>` tags don't specify a width/height. This is why. Have the server include those attributes and the browser will automatically allocate the space, allowing you to use the `scrollHeight` accurately.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks! I'll confirm this works as soon as I get back to my development workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readyState` property of your XmlHttpRequest() to estimate when it's finished loading.

```
xmlhttpobject.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.querySelector("#myDiv").scrollTop = document.querySelector("#myDiv").scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)